# Uncaught TypeError: PHP from requests Method

Tags: php, typeerror, php-7

I have problem with PHP 7 on my code

**Constract Class**

```
class FETCH_STRUCTURE{
    const FETCH_ARRAY     = 0;
    const FETCH_OBJECT    = 1;}
```

**Method in another Class**

```
public function setPostDataStructure(FETCH_STRUCTURE $postDataStructure)
    {
            $this->postDataStructure = $postDataStructure;
    }

function getPostDataStructure():FETCH_STRUCTURE {
    return $this->postDataStructure;
}
```

**Call Method from Class**

> Uncaught TypeError: Return value of myClass::getPostDataStructure() must implement interface FETCH_STRUCTURE, integer returned

```
$this->view->setPostDataStructure(  FETCH_STRUCTURE::FETCH_ARRAY );

echo $this->view->getPostDataStructure();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `FETCH_STRUCTURE::FETCH_ARRAY` is an integer (`0`) as defined by your constant in `FETCH_STRUCTURE`. You are passing that value to the `setPostDataStructure` method which in turn is assigning that value (`0`) to your `$this->postDataStructure` property.

The return value of `getPostDataStructure` is defined as the class `FETCH_STRUCTURE` but in fact you are returning the integer `0`.

If your intention is to return an integer you should do this:

```
function getPostDataStructure():int {
    return $this->postDataStructure;
}
```

If your intention is to return an instance of the `FETCH_STRUCTURE` class you should *set* an instance of that class with the `setPostDataStructure` method.